# Recursive function: Save output of every call to list

Tags: r, list, recursion, functional-programming

I would like to save the output of every function call of the following recursive function to a list.  Moreover, I need to know which (j,l)-pair correspond to which entry of the resulting list.

I have created a stripped down version to reproduce the problem.  Please let me know if I should provide more information to help solve the problem.  Any help is highly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
#the recursive function
phi <- function(phik,j,l,k,d) {
  if(j==0) {
    diag(d)
  }
  else{
    if(j==1) {
      if(l>k) {
        0 * diag(d)
      }
      else{
        phik[[l]]      
      }      
    }
    else {
      if(l>k) {
        0 + phi(phik,j-1,l,k,d) %*% phik[[1]]
      }
      else {
        phi(phik,j-1,l+1,k,d) + phi(phik,j-1,l,k,d) %*% phik[[1]]
      }      
    }
  }
}

#related stuff
set.seed(123456)
phik <- vector(mode="list", length=3)
phik[[1]] <- matrix(rnorm(n=16,mean=0,s=1),nrow=4)
phik[[2]] <- matrix(rnorm(n=16,mean=0,s=1),nrow=4)
phik[[3]] <- matrix(rnorm(n=16,mean=0,s=1),nrow=4)
d <- nrow(phik[[1]])
k <- length(phik)

#function call
phiout <- phi(phik,j=10,l=1,k=k,d=d)
```

Comment: you are not producing any output; you are returning values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it is a little tricky with recursive functions, because if you want the results of the intermediate steps, you have glue them together in a list. Of course, that means when you use the results of the recursion in the function, you have to dig out the value that you want. That sounds a little convoluted, but in your case, I just mean that you have to return a little list of `phi`, `j`, and `l` at every step, but pull out just `phi` when you do the multiplications. Here is a little example:

```
#the recursive function
phi <- function(phik,j,l,k,d) {
  if(j==0) 
    list(list(phi=diag(d),j=j,l=l))
  else{
    if(j==1) {
      if(l>k) 
        list(list(phi=0 * diag(d),j=j,l=l))
      else 
        list(list(phi=phik[[l]],j=j,l=l))
    }
    else {
      if(l>k) {
        first<-phi(phik,j-1,l,k,d)
        second<-list(list(phi=0 + first[[1]]$phi %*% phik[[1]], j=j,l=l))
        c(second,first)
      }
      else {
        first<-phi(phik,j-1,l+1,k,d) 
        second<-phi(phik,j-1,l,k,d) 
        third<-list(list(phi=first[[1]]$phi+(second[[1]]$phi %*% phik[[1]]), j=j, l=l))
        c(third,first,second)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You might be interested in why I nested the results in the first to third cases (when `j` is 0 or 1). If you look at the other cases, it might become clear. When `l>k` (and `j` is not 0 or 1), then there are two calls `phi` made. In this case, there will be a `list` returned, with two sets of `phi`, `i`, and `j`, so it is necessarily a `list` of `list`s. When I want to pull out `phi` from a returned value, it is difficult to tell whether it was going to be just a `list` or a `list` of `list`s, so I just standardized them all to the same thing.

I think `return` statements are ugly, but others disagree. You can add them in if you like, but they are strictly unnecessary (in this case).

Some sample output:

```
set.seed(123456)
phik <- vector(mode="list", length=3)
phik[[1]] <- matrix(rnorm(n=16,mean=0,s=1),nrow=4)
phik[[2]] <- matrix(rnorm(n=16,mean=0,s=1),nrow=4)
phik[[3]] <- matrix(rnorm(n=16,mean=0,s=1),nrow=4)
d <- nrow(phik[[1]])
k <- length(phik)

phi(phik,j=2,l=3,k,d)
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$phi
#            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
# [1,] -0.9087417 -2.064341 -0.9962198  0.7713081
# [2,] -2.9595280 -5.330120 -4.0488408  2.3357631
# [3,] -1.3754167 -3.866457 -0.8592336  1.4135614
# [4,] -0.1021518 -4.332802  0.4883886 -2.2130314
# 
# [[1]]$j
# [1] 2
# 
# [[1]]$l
# [1] 3
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$phi
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0
# 
# [[2]]$j
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]$l
# [1] 4
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]]$phi
#            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
# [1,] -1.0461983  1.560074 -1.0713045  0.1582893
# [2,] -2.7488684  1.015088  0.9678209 -0.5019485
# [3,] -1.1298596  1.043994  0.1710325 -0.9659226
# [4,] -0.8616848 -1.115905 -0.8962503 -0.1137341
# 
# [[3]]$j
# [1] 1
# 
# [[3]]$l
# [1] 3
```